# React js, javascript not filtering properly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i am trying to make a filter feature for a website i am working on, i am using an html range slider. The problem is that the values update just if they are going down, for example if i set the slider to $500, only the products that cost $500 or less will appear, if i set the value lower, it's going to work how is supposed to work, but if i try to set the value bigger, the items will not filter, for example, the value is set to $500, if  set the value to $600 only the items that are $500 or less will render, but not the $600 ones.

here is my code:

```
const Shop = () => {

      const [sliderValue, setValue] = useState(0);
      const [filterItems, setApplyFilter] = useState(false);
      const [newData, setData] = useState(data);
    
      const checkChange = () => {
        if (sliderValue > 3) {
          setApplyFilter(true);
        } else {
          setApplyFilter(false);
        }
        console.log(applyFilter);
      };
    
      const applyFilter = () => {
        if (filterItems === true) {
          const filteredData = newData.filter((item) => item.price <= sliderValue);
          console.log(filteredData);
          setData(filteredData);
        } else {
          setData(data);
        }
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        checkChange();
        applyFilter();
      }, [sliderValue]);
    
      const handleChange = (value) => {
        setValue(value);
      };
      return (
           <div className="slider-container">
                <input
                type="range"
                min={0}
                max={1000}
                value={sliderValue}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
                className="slider"
                />
            </div>
      );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setData([...filteredData])?

Comment: Tried it now, it does not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem: you are changing the `data` with `setData()`, so every time you move your scrollbar this deletes some data. If you want to keep a `constant` information that is available to all your application, consider using [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). This creates a persistent object for the full lifetime of the component.

```js
import { useRef } from 'react'

const Shop = () => {
   const dataArr = useRef(data) 
   ...
   const applyFilter = () => {
        if (filterItems === true) {
          // Access with "current" attribute
          const filteredData = dataArr.current
                                      .filter((item) => item.price <= sliderValue);
          setData(filteredData);
        }
   }
}
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/rt62js1k/1/)

Comment: This answer copies a subset of items from your original list into a new state slice. None of which is necessary. Please consider my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's something to do with this two lines:

```
const filteredData = newData.filter((item) => item.price <= sliderValue);
setData(filteredData);
```

Once you have filtered your data once, the value of `newData` in your state will be only the already filtered data.

Let's say we start with prices: `newData`=[100, 200, 300, 400]

We filter it for the first time down to 200, so now `newData`=[100, 200]

Next we filter up to 300, but `newData` only has [100, 200]

So just change those two lines for:

```
const filteredData = data.filter((item) => item.price <= sliderValue);
setData(filteredData);
```

This is asuming you have a variable `data` declared or imported somewhere with the comple data set.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need state for data array since it can be determined on every render based on some other state.

```
const Shop = ({ inputData }) => {
  const [sliderValue, setValue] = useState(0);

  // This flag is deterministic based on sliderValue, so determine it here
  const filterItems = sliderValue > 3;

  // The items that will make it past the filter are deterministic, based on your filterItems flag
  // so no state is necessary
  const renderItems = filterItems ? inputData.filter(i => i.price <= sliderValue) : inputData;

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  return ...
};
```